# How to print result with maximum value under each header?

Tags: perl

I have data and perl code as following. I am trying to find letter combination with maximum score (last column) under each header (>dna1, >dna2) and print it. I wrote code in Perl as following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($line);
my $max = 0;
my @prediction;
foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        print "$line";
    }
    else {
        my @split = split(/\s+/,$line);
        my $score = pop @split;
        if ($max < $score) {
            $max = $score;
            @prediction = @split;
            push @prediction, $max;
        }
    #print "$domain\n";
    }
    print "@prediction\n";
}
__DATA__
>dna1
D   124.6
D T   137.5
G   -3.4
G T   9.5
T   12.9
>dna2
A   196.3
A K   186.5
A K H   192.7
A H M   206.2
A M   200
```

The output is

```
>dna1
D 124.6
D T 137.5
D T 137.5
D T 137.5
D T 137.5
>dna2D T 137.5
A 196.3
A 196.3
A 196.3
A H M 206.2
A H M 206.2
```

Could you please help me to figure out how I can get output just final combination with max score as following:

```
>dna1
D T 137.5
>dna2
A H M 206.2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces the expected output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($max_score, $max_combination);
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        print "$max_combination $max_score\n" if $max_combination;

        print $line;
        $max_score = 0;

    } elsif (my ($combination, $score) = $line =~ /(.*)\s+([0-9.]+)/) {
        if ($score > $max_score) {
            $max_score       = $score;
            $max_combination = $combination;
        }
    }
}
print "$max_combination $max_score\n";
```

The main difference is you need to print the result only when a new group starts, or at the very end.

Comment: changing $line to $_ is a step backwards IMO

Comment: @LingZhang Do you understand how it works, and why your code does not work? If not, maybe choroba can add an explanation.

Comment: @ i alarmed alien. Thank you for your reminder. Yes, I understand it. In my code, I used foreach, so print combination with max score at each iteration. Choroba used "while" here by which I could print the final result before every new group. Thanks again.

Comment: @LingZhang `foreach` and `while` are just ways to go through an array--choroba's code could be rewritten with a `foreach` loop. The problem with your code was that you were printing the results every line, rather than at the end of each 'section'.